# Zechariah 2 whom is speaking, who is whom and saying what exactly?

Tags: commentaries, zecharia-book-of

Looking at Zechariah [2:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.2.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)-15 it reads:

“For thus said the LORD of Hosts..”
“ Then you shall know that I was sent by the LORD of Hosts...”
“For lo, I come; and I will dwell in your midst—declares the LORD...”
“ In that day many nations will attach themselves to the LORD and become His people, and He will dwell in your midst. Then you will know that I was sent to you by the LORD of Hosts.”

Who says what to whom, and whom
is sending whom?

Comment: *who is speaking, who is who, and saying what, exactly ?* - This exact question is a perpetual leitmotif when it comes to reading and understanding prophetic or apocalyptic literature. There are many others like it, both on this Jewish site, as well as on the related hermeneutics site.

Comment: Maybe the earliest of these quandaries occurs where Hashem shows Moshe an image of Himself wrapped in a tallis and praying (the 13 middos ha'rachamim). As Rav Hutner points out, who is Hashem praying to?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE quite interesting.